# What are the odds?

Tags: probability

I am trying to create a *unique* code for people who create an object in my application. I am wanting to determine the odds of the same *unique* code being generated. This may depend on how I generate random numbers, but for the sake of this exercise if we can pretend they're absolutely random and that would be fine.

The unique code consists of:

1. The current date (e.g. 10102015)

I then generate an 8 character code using the following:

1. Generate a random number between 1 and 100

If the random number is between 1 and 75 then I generate a second random number between 1 and 26 and assign the character to the correlating letter of the alphabet.

If the random number is between 75 and 100 then I generate a random number between 0 and 9 and assign the character this number.

For example, a final code might look like:
10102015gy7e4f5g

As the initial part of the code is date based the final figure will be the chance of this repeating on a single day. Which Im guessing is a ridiculously high number (hopefully).

EDIT:

The reasons this is being done this way is because the application is an 'offline' application, but has the functionality to push certain things (called Boards in the app) to other users.

From the comments below I've figured a better way to do this now. But still, interested to know how many possible combinations this way would produce.
Thanks :D

Comment: Bad technique. Instead use incremental IDs. Or, if you insist, check if the generated number already exists. If so, regenerate (and check again).

Comment: A better way is to ensure the random number is unique, which can be done a few of different ways.  Here are two: 1) you can simply generate a random number, check if it's unique and if not generate another and loop until you get a unique number or 2) you can keep a list of numbers and then randomly choose an index and then delete that number from your list.  Which one you choose really depends on memory requirements: if a collision is unlikely then the first way uses virtually no memory, but if your range is small enough to put each one into memory then the other way may run faster.

Comment: Also, to actually answer your question, you would have to tell us the number of users you expect to create an object on a single date.  If it's two per day, then the odds are $\frac{1}{100^2}$, but as the number increases it basically becomes the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)...which means it won't take very many to make a collision likely.

Comment: As for the mathematics of the probability calculations, are you looking for the probability that two codes (generated on the same day) are identical?  The probability that out of a day with...say...a thousand codes being generated, that there are no repeats?  The probability that out of a month with, say, a million codes being generated that there are no repeats?

Comment: @Jared he will generate an 8 character code.  Making a huge simplification that every alphanumeric character is equally likely (which appears to be what he attempted to do), it becomes $\frac{1}{36^{8}}$ for two codes to match (assuming they were generated on the same day)

Comment: There's another aspect as well, which is how long is this program expected to run.  Even if you only have two users per day at a probability of collision of $\frac{1}{10000}$, you would expect one collision every 27 years--which is probably an acceptable risk (although a program which runs for 27 years is unlikely to only have two users per day).

Comment: @dbanet - There are issues with plain incremental IDs due to the nature of the app (or more likely, my lack of skill in this area). I'll update the question with more detail on this shortly. Your second point is what I'm currently doing which works fine, but creates additional calls to the server. Part of what I want to know is, how many additional calls should I expect - I can answer that If I know the probability of this number coming up.

Comment: @JMoravitz he specifically stated that he would generate a random number from 1 to 100.

Comment: @Jared which is then used to determine whether the next character in the code is either a numeral or a letter, then proceeds to randomly determine which character to use of that type.  Loop that eight times to construct the entire code.  See OP's post: "*a final code might look like: 10102015gy7e4f5g*"

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I don't understand why the number of users matters? Whether it's 1 person or 50 people generating the code shouldn't matter. The total amount of codes generated would matter though? Would you not just work out how many possible combination this method could produce and that would be the probability (I'll probably get slapped for that comment)...

Comment: @JMoravitz OK good point, I guess I didn't care to look that carefully when you can generate a random 32-bit integer quite easily in virtually all programming languages which makes collisions virtually impossible.  And you could easily scale such an application by starting with a certain range and then extending it when necessary.

Comment: I won't slap you for it @user241420 but rather remind you that this is in essence a rewording of the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), as already mentioned by Jared above.  With the oversimplification that you correct your method of randomly generating the characters (it would be easier to do a random integer from 1 to 36, assigning the results of 1 through 26 to the corresponding letters and 27 through 36 to the numbers 0 through 9) so that every sequence is equally likely, instead of 365 birthdays, you have $36^8\approx 2.8\times 10^{12}$ "*birthdays*."

Comment: OK - Thanks all. The better way for me to do this is: a) Use incremental as @dbanet mentioned and when a board is shared I replace the incremental with the unique objectId generated by Parse.... appreciate all your comments.

Comment: @user241420 I would caution against using incremental IDs.  The IDs should have no meaning, but if you use incremental IDs, although they will be unique, if someone has access to those IDs, they actually _do_ have meaning: which is a "later" ID tells you about how many people are accessing your program.  So by using incremental IDs, you inadvertently embed information that should not be embedded.  This is a privacy/security issue.  Privacy because it gives a hacker information about your usage and security because it makes forging an ID easy (a hacker can pretend to be someone they're not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all characters are in fact equally likely, there are $36^8\approx 2.8\times 10^{12} \approx 2^{42}$ unique codes which can be generated on a single day.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table) has a table of values on its page about the Birthday Problem (which this is a rewording of), showing that for a scenario with a few fewer available codes (half as many) then with $1.5\times 10^5$ users on a given day, there would be a $1\%$ chance of (*at least one*) repeated code.  With 4700 users the probability is around $0.1\%$ (one in a thousand).  With 150 users on a given day, the probability of a repeated code would be a $1\times 10^{-6}$ (one in a million).  With 47 users on a given day, it would be one in a billion.

With $8\times 10^5$ users the probability has gone up considerably to $25\%$ chance of a collision, and with $1.2\times 10^6$, the probability of a collision is over $50\%$.  (A somewhat surprising result, despite having over a trillion unique id's available, it only requires a million users to have the probability of at least two people generating the same id be worse than $50\%$).

The expected waiting time until having a collision is $\frac{1}{p}$ (see [negative-binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)).  For example, if you have 4700 users per day, you should be able to expect it to run for 1000 days without any duplicate ids.

---

(*the real odds will be somewhat different for two reasons, the estimates I used were for equally likely sequences.  As your pseudocode has a preference for letters rather than numbers, chances of matches will be higher and the odds slightly* **worse** *.  However, to offset this, I rounded down to the nearest entry on the table which uses fewer available sequences making matches more likely, causing your odds to be slightly* **better** *.  In all, even through the simplifications and estimates I wouldn't expect the true values to vary by more than an order of magnitude from those given here*).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your detailed answer.